# Regex to replace words separated by underscore in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to replace specific words (separated by a specific word boundary of underscore) with Python. I know i can just do a string split and loop through the list items to replace the key phrases and then re-join it into string afterwards.. but it does not feel like the most elegant or the best way to go about doing it.

So, let's say I create a small function based on regex for the purposes of what i want to do, something like this:

```
def replace_words(string, rep_dict, separator):
    regex = r'({0}|\b)({1})({2}|\b)'.format(re.escape(separator), '|'.join(rep_dict.keys()), re.escape(separator))
    return re.sub(regex, lambda x: '{0}{1}{2}'.format(x.group(1), rep_dict[x.group(2)], x.group(3)), string)
```

Suppose i use any other separator, like for example an asterisk (*), then it works as intended:

```
 rep_odds = {'first': '1st', 'third': '3rd', 'fifth': '5th'}
 rep_evens = {'second': '2nd', 'fourth': '4th'}
 orders = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
 before = '*'.join(orders)
 after = replace_words(before, rep_odds, separator='*')
 # returns: 1st*second*3rd*fourth*5th
 after = replace_words(before, {**rep_odds, **rep_evens}, separator='*')
 # returns: 1st*2nd*3rd*4th*5th
```

But if i change this to use the separator as underscore (_) instead, I get this unexpected and (wrong) behavior:

```
before = '_'.join(orders)
after = replace_words(before, rep_odds, separator='_')
# returns: 1st_second_3rd_fourth_5th <-- Good
after = replace_words(before, {**rep_odds, **rep_evens}, separator='_')
# returns: 1st_second_3rd_fourth_5th <-- What went wrong ?!
```

If someone can help me understand this behavior, I am still kind of new to learning regex and how it works in Python ... thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of input and desired output?

Comment: Does `orders` change in any case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neat problem. Here's the issue:

`re.sub` does not allow one character to lie in multiple matching groups; once a character belongs to a match, it is consumed, unless you specify that the match be nonconsuming. When matching using the asterisk, a key fact was that a word boundary lies between an asterisk and a word character. Here are the matching groups when using the asterisk (the `{0}`, `{1}`, and `{2}` in the `lambda`):

```
('', 'first', '*')
('', 'second', '*')
('', 'third', '*')
('', 'fourth', '*')
('', 'fifth', '')
```

When the regex matcher hits the end of the first match, its cursor is between the first asterisk and the word `second`, which is at a word boundary. Hence `second*` is also a match, and then `third*`, etc.

However, when you use an underscore, here are the corresponding matches:

```
('', 'first', '_')
('_', 'third', '_')
('_', 'fifth', '')
```

When the regex matcher hits the end of the first match, its cursor is between the first underscore and the word `second` , which is *not* a word boundary. Since it's already passed the first underscore and isn't at a word boundary, it can't match `(_|\b)second`. Hence there is no match until the next underscore after `second`, and you can see that that match includes both underscores adjacent to `third`.

In short, the first example was "lucky" in that after passing the separator character, you'd land in a word boundary, which was not the case for the second example.

To fix this, you can use a lookahead assertion, which will not consume the matched characters.

```
def replace_words(string, rep_dict, separator):
    regex = r'({0}|\b)({1})((?={2}|\b).*?)'.format(
        re.escape(separator), '|'.join(rep_dict.keys()), re.escape(separator)
    )

    return re.sub(
        regex, lambda x: '{0}{1}{2}'.
        format(x.group(1), rep_dict[x.group(2)], x.group(3)), string
    )
```

The matches are now the following:

```
('', 'first', '')
('*', 'second', '')
('*', 'third', '')
('*', 'fourth', '')
('*', 'fifth', '')
```

Ignore the struck-through text below, which would have matched on word prefixes, e.g. `*firstperson*` would have become `*1stperson*`.

P.S. Splitting and rejoining is probably your best bet. This is most likely what re.sub is doing under the hood anyway, since strings are immutable.

<s>To fix this, you can match only on the separator character preceding a keyword *or* the start of the string (alternatively, the separator character following a keyword *or* the end of the string).</s>

```
def replace_words(string, rep_dict, separator):
    regex = r'(^|{0})({1})'.format(
        re.escape(separator), '|'.join(rep_dict.keys())
    )

    return re.sub(
        regex, lambda x: print(x.groups()) or '{0}{1}'.
        format(x.group(1), rep_dict[x.group(2)]), string
    )
```

Comment: ... or you can use lookaheads and/or lookbehinds to find but not consume the separator.

Comment: I do appreciate the wonderful explanation! I thought it was something to do with word boundary because '\w' also lists the underscore as one of its characters. I will try out the solution you gave and but I agree I think splitting in this case will work the best.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't directly ansnwer your question, but isn't this:

```
def replace_words(s, rep_dict, sep):
    return sep.join(rep_dict.get(word, word) for word in s.split(sep))
```

more elegant than the regex solution (which anyway uses `join`)?

Comment: Your right, I was leaning towards using split and join method since I had to use join for the regex either way.. but I was curious to see if it could be done better without it. anyway I think ill just stick with what you outlined here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `regex` if I understand you properly.

```
rep_odds = {'first': '1st', 'third': '3rd', 'fifth': '5th'}
rep_evens = {'second': '2nd', 'fourth': '4th'}
orders = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']

print('_'.join([rep_odds.get(x, rep_evens.get(x, 0)) for x in orders]))
# 1st_2nd_3rd_4th_5th
```

You could generalize this to use with any separator or any order of `orders` like:

```
def fun(sep, orders):
    print(sep.join([rep_odds.get(x, rep_evens.get(x, 0)) for x in orders]))

fun('*', orders)
# 1st*2nd*3rd*4th*5th
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
z=dict(rep_odds.items() + rep_evens.items())
for i,item in enumerate(orders):
    orders[i]=z.get(item)
```

Output:

```
print(orders)
['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th']
```